# Through image I browsed images but not able to submit the same

Tags: javascript, php, html

Through image I want to browse  images  for that I have taken div and hided the field img_photo and called a function i.e OpenFileBrowser() on anchor tab. I am able to browse images but not able to submit the form.

```
HTML :
<form name="frmimg" id="frmimg" method="post" action="abc.php"> 
<div style="display:none"><input type="file" name="img_photo" id="img_photo" value="" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png"></div>
<a href="wap_statusupadate.php?img=<?php echo $_REQUEST['hid_img']; ?>" onclick="return OpenFileBrows
er('frmimg')"><img src="images/photo-icon.jpg" /></a>
</form>

Javascript :
function OpenFileBrowser(obj)
{
    document.getElementById('img_photo').click();
    var img =   document.getElementById('img_photo').value;
    if(img!="")   
    {
        document.obj.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the form will be submitted through HTML only if we are submitting it using a submit button.

Comment: @Jenz - but I want to submit the form by using anchor tab only

Comment: plz try with the answer I have posted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
document.getElementById('frmimg').submit();
```

to the end of function OpenFileBrowser(obj).

Comment: the problem here is on first click we select images and on second click it get image name and then it submits the form. It does not get image name on first click.

Comment: as said by you it is only possible by adding submit button. Thank you for your reply.